# Fs.readFile on FTP server

Tags: node.js, ftp, fs

I've got some script in Node.js which is working when I run it on my computer but not when I'm on a server.
I've got 2 servers: I run the webApplication on the first (Server 1) and the second (Server 2) contains files.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var FTPClient = require('ftp');
var c = new FTPClient();

c.connect({
  host: "192.168.200.2",
  user: "*****",
  password: "******"
});

c.on('ready', function() {

  console.log("Connected to datastore !");

  var dateFile = './Dictionnary/lastUpdate.json';
  var csvFile = '//192.168.200.2/Alfa/file4457.csv'
  var lastUpdate;

  fs.stat(csvFile, (err, stat) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    };

    var date = { mtime: stat.mtime }

    var lastDate = new Date(jsonfile.readFileSync(dateFile).mtime);

    var newDate = new Date(stat.mtime);

    if (newDate <= lastDate) {
      console.log('Dictionnary up-to-date');
    } else {
      console.log('Update Needed');
      var DeleteQuery = mySqlClient.query('DELETE FROM dictionnary');
      csv = fs.readFile(csvFile, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err
        };
        dictionnary = parseCSV(data);
        for (i = 0; i < dictionnary.length - 1; i++) {
          var insertQuery = ("INSERT INTO Dictionnary VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
          var query = mySqlClient.query(insertQuery, [dictionnary[i][0], dictionnary[i][1], dictionnary[i][2], dictionnary[i][3], dictionnary[i][4], dictionnary[i][5], dictionnary[i][6], dictionnary[i][7], dictionnary[i][8], dictionnary[i][9], dictionnary[i][10], , dictionnary[i][11], , dictionnary[i][12]]);
         };
      }
   }
}
```

When I run the script on my computer I can find the file on the (Server 2) but when I run it on the (server 1) it doesn't work anymore and I've this error:

```
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '//192.168.200.2/Alfa/file4457.csv'
```

I thought it was a problem with the pass so I tried with `//192.168.200.2/Alfa/file4457.csv`, `./Alfa/file4457.csv`, `Alfa/file4457.csv`

But that's not working.

I checked the path and he's good.

For the `fs.stat()` that's not a problem I can still replace it by `c.lastMod()` but I don't find what I can use to replace the `fs.readFile()`

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fs` will look the path you give to it `//192.168.200.2/Alfa/file4457.csv`.

From the server you're executing the script, this path is not found. I don't know your network and servers architecture so I can't really explain why it works on your computer and not on the server. But I guess your computer and the FTP server are on the same local network (correctme if I'm wrong).

After reading your code, you're opening a FTP connection on a remote FTP server :

```
c.connect({
  host: "192.168.200.2",
  user: "*****",
  password: "******"
});

c.on('ready', function() {
    ...
});
```

But int the `.on('ready', function() { ... })` callback you don't do anything with this new openned connection (look at your code, you never use `c` again).

By reading the `ftp` node module [documentation](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp), you can find that there is the `get` function, able to retrieve a file from your FTP connection.

> get(< string >path, [< boolean >useCompression, ]< function >callback)
>   - (void) - Retrieves a file at path from the server. useCompression defaults to false. callback has 2 parameters: < Error >err, <
>   ReadableStream >fileStream.

So, you have to use the FTP connection with something like that :

```
c.connect({
   host: "192.168.200.2",
   user: "*****",
   password: "******"
});

c.on('ready', function() {
    c.get('/Alfa/file4457.csv', function(err, stream) {
         var content = '';
         stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
             content += chunk.toString();
         });
         stream.on('end', function() {
             // content variable now contains all file content. 
         });
    })
});
```

Comment: with the stream can I have access to the content of the file ?

Comment: Of course, I updated my answer, take a look at the documentation : https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: Thank you very much